# Why is there no weak type detection on a empty object

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I'm reading the typescript docs and have come across the following.

> TypeScript 2.4 introduces the concept of “weak types”. Any type that
> contains nothing but a set of all-optional properties is considered to
> be weak.
>
> In TypeScript 2.4, it’s now an error to assign anything to a weak type when there’s no overlap in properties.

However, I can assign an empty object {} to a weak type and the compiler wont throw any errors.
Why is this, as there is no overlap in properties.

Comment: I think you should read: _In TypeScript 2.4, it’s now an error to assign anything to a weak type when there are non-overlappping properties._

Comment: I think that is where I quoted from.

Comment: It is in the semantics of the words. An empty object equals a partial. It is an error when your object contains properties that are not part of the partial.

Comment: [Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMsiHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzEC+xxoksiKAQRDAKcADb5ipOMNFiAKgE8ADjToNmbIpyLEEOeshkjxtISYkBeSSSOzxS1bQDk+gO7OOW4gHofyRxRnczlnZAALOAwyLGRlKCxVKDBgCGjQZH0KChxkN2AwcOQwFSDUOGTgcQAedChsEAA+ZwA6PQMwOMwccsrTNAqUmrqGxuRrYzlvIj9kADVxYAATGOQKYAwMZjiEpJS09pBDJIbeobEAJlozqrFa7qbx-GR2LSA)

Comment: @Silvermind. Great. Thanks so much. I didn't know what partial was. Gonna look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A weak type is essentiale the same as a `Partial<StrongType>`.

It means: If there are properties, but non of them match the partials properties.
In other words: If you assign an object that has no properties that exist in the target type, it produces an error.

A partial is effectively the same as an empty object `{}`.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
}

interface Animal {
  animalType: string;
}

const animal: Animal = {
  animalType: 'cow'
};

// Type 'Animal' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Person>'.
const personPartial: Partial<Person> = animal;

// Valid, there are no additional properties
const personPartial2: Partial<Person> = { };
```

If you add a name property to the animal type it would accept it though.